Symbol Lookup Error with lsusb
I'm trying to run lsusb on my Ubuntu system, but I keep getting the error: symbol lookup error: lsusb: undefined symbol: libusb_get_port_number. I've already tried reinstalling libusb and lsusb, but the issue persists. How can I resolve this?

Thanks for your reply @guiverc. I’m running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa). For me, lsusb is part of the usbutils package. Here’s the output from lsb_release -a: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
Any advise given this setup? What do you think?
